# If the norm of a path is a constant, is the derivative always zero?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $\gamma(t):[a,b]\to\Bbb{R^n}$ is a continuously differentiable path and $\vert \gamma(t)\vert=\int_a^b\vert\gamma'(t)\vert \enspace dt=C$, where $C$ is a constant, and this relation is true for all $t\in[a,b].$ Now, if we differentiate both sides of the relation with respect to $t$, we have $\vert \gamma'(t) \vert =0$ and therefore $\gamma'(t)=0$ for all $t\in[a,b]$ correct?

Comment: $\vert \gamma(t)\vert=\int_a^b\vert\gamma'(t)\vert \enspace dt$ is wrong anyway.  (The left side is a function of $t$, the right side is a constant.) But it is true that if a function is equal to a constant (as shown in the incorrect equation), then the function has derivative zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not correct. Consider $\gamma(t)=( \cos t, \sin t)$ for $t \in [a,b]=[0,1]$ and $C=1$

Then $| \gamma(t)|= |\gamma'(t)|=1.$